# How do I incorporate a print function into a program that calculates perimeters and identifies shapes?

Tags: java, string, function, printing

I am struggling to continue to work on my shape identifier/perimeter calculator program. I need to figure out how I can incorporate a print function into my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sideA;
    int sideB;
    int sideC;
    int sideD;

    System.out.println("Enter side 1: ");
    sideA = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter side 2: ");
    sideB = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter side 3: ");
    sideC = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter side 4: ");
    sideD = scan.nextInt();

    int perimeter = add(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD);

    if (sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC && sideC == sideD && sideD == sideA) {
        System.out.println("Forms a square with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Does not form a square.");
    }

}

private static int add(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sideD) {
    return sideA + sideB + sideC + sideD;
}

public class shapePerimeter {
    String shape;
    int perimeter;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Forms a " + shape + " with a perimeter of " + perimeter);
    }
}
```

The last public class, as seen above, is my attempt at a print function. How can I correct this if it has any problems with modifiers, return types, parameters, and statements?

Comment: Your print method would probably be better as a method in the Main class.  If you want to keep the print as a separate class, you have to pass the shape and perimeter into the class using a constructor or pass the shape and perimeter into the print method itself.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want to keep everything separated into two classes, but what I would suggest is shifting your if/else statement inside of your main into its own method inside the shapePerimeter class. This way you can just extend the ShapePerimeter class to your main one and call the add() method and the this new method within a constructor of your main class to assign your two variables. From here I would then just move the code inside your print() method into the main class and restructure the print so it'll print the assigned variables in your constructor.

Here's a solution:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator extends ShapePerimeter {
    int perimeter;
    String shape;

    public Calculator(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sideD) {
        perimeter = add(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD);
        shape = identifier(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sideA;
        int sideB;
        int sideC;
        int sideD;

        System.out.println("Enter side 1: ");
        sideA = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter side 2: ");
        sideB = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter side 3: ");
        sideC = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter side 4: ");
        sideD = scan.nextInt();

        Calculator calc = new Calculator(sideA, sideB, sideC, sideD);

        System.out.println(calc.shape + " with a perimeter of " + calc.perimeter);
    }
}


public class ShapePerimeter {

    public String identifier(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sideD) {
        if (sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC && sideC == sideD && sideD == sideA) {
            return "Forms a square";
        } else {
            return "Does not form a square";
        }        
    }

    public int add(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sideD) {
        return sideA + sideB + sideC + sideD;
    }
}
```

Notice that by creating the constructor we are now able to just make an object of our class, pass through our user inputs for the object's parameters, and then return the object's assigned variables for our print statement. Hope this helps!